# Angular Js routing not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

i am new on angularjs. I have done all regarding routing but its not working. I want my home page will be the default page. Whenever i open index.php page, it shows black screen. Here is my code,

```
//index.php
<body ng-app="app">
        <!-- HEADER AND NAVBAR -->
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/angularjs">Angular JS Practice</a>
                    </div>

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#students"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> Student</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div ng-view></div>

            <script type = "text/ng-template" id = "home.htm">
                <h2> {{pagename}} </h2>
                {{message}}
            </script>

            <script type = "text/ng-template" id = "students.htm">
                <h2> {{pagename}} </h2>
                {{message}}
            </script>

        </div>
        <!--1.4.8-->
        <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>  
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
```

App.js

```
var app=angular.module('app',['ngRoute']);


app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when("/",{
        templeteUrl:"home.htm",
        controller:'myctrl'
    }).when("/students",{
        templateUrl:"students.htm",
        controller:"studentCtrl"
    }).otherwise({
        templateUrl:"404.php",
        controller:"notfoundCtrl"
    })

}]);

app.controller("notfoundCtrl",function($scope){
    $scope.pagename='Not Found';
    $scope.message='The page you are request not found';

});

app.controller("studentCtrl",function($scope){
    $scope.pagename='Students';
    $scope.message="This is student page"; 
});

app.controller("myctrl",function($scope){
   $scope.pagename="Home Page";
   $scope.message="This is home page";
});
```

Comment: What's the problem? Be more accurate, what happens when you try to navigate? How do you navigate? What Url's do you use? ...

Comment: Edited my question. By default it shows black screen. It should show home page content

Comment: What kind of errors do you see in the console. Are you able to navigate to other pages?

Comment: @WildWidow no console error. Yes students link is working fine.

Comment: You have templeteUrl instead of templateUrl.?

Comment: It is also a good practice to set the base href property to just "/" in the head section of your html

Comment: @WildWidow well thanks, it was a very stupid mistake. I am closing this question.

Comment: Just FYI, Angular's URL based routing is kind of old,  it is better to use state based routing instead, it offers nested views and many other functionalities.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111712/discussion-between-maha-dev-and-wild-widow).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wrote `templeteUrl:"home.htm"`, can you try changing that to `templateUrl:"home.htm"`?

Answer (score 0):

you have a syntax error :`templateUrl instead of templeteUrl`